# Move-SPUser to convert users only in 1 webapplication

Tags: powershell, migration, sharepoint-on-prem, user-accounts

In on-premise farm, I understand that using Move-SPUser will update the user identity in all the web applications in the farm.

Is there a recommend approach wherein I can use Move-SPUser to update user identity only in 1 web application?

Answer (score 0):

`Move-SPUser` and `stsadm -o migrateuser` are farm-wide operations. There is no way to restrict identity migration to a single Web Application.

There are 3rd party products that can accomplish this, like Metalogix ControlPoint can clone permissions within a specific scope.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I made all the content DBs in the farm as read-only except the DB that are part of the web application that I would like to convert . I then ran Move-SPuser command, this converted the user identities only in DBs that are not set to read-only. Can this approach be followed?

Comment: The problem is the UPS will see the 'move' and will also attempt to move the user. The approach you took is /likely/ unsupported, but that would be a better question to bring up with Microsoft.